# How can I get the following layout of bullet points?

Tags: bullets

The first slide:
bullet point A

The second slide:
bullet point A
bullet point B

The third slide:
bullet point A
bullet point B
bullet point C

The fourth slide:
bullet point A
bullet point B
bullet point C
bullet point D

The fifth slide:
bullet point A
bullet point E

So I want the position of the first bullet point on the screen to be fixed, otherwise, I can build the above slide individually.
I believe there are orders that can make the bullet point appear only once or stay after the first appearance. But in my case, it is "stay after the first appearance until a certain slide".

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify, but I assume that you want to do this in a `beamer` presentation? You can define overlay specifications with angled brackets `<>` after the `\item`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item<2-4> B
    \item<3-4> C
    \item<4> D
    \item<5> E
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

They can also be used for more than just items, for example by using the `\only` or `\visible` macros -- see the section on Overlay Specifications in the [excellent beamer manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer?lang=en).

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear from your question whether you want to have E replace B or to appear below where D was before. I recommend to have a look at the [documentation of the `beamer` class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) which describes the overlay options in detail. Here is a solution where E replaces B from the 5th slide onwards.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> A
\item<2-> \alt<5->{E}{B}
% or \item<2-> \only<-4>{B}\only<5->{E}
\item<3-4> C
\item<4> D
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]